# How to show @item value with its own icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
    @{ foreach (TestMachine item in Model)
        { <tr>
                <td>@item.OS</td>
                }}
```

In my @item.OS have only two choice. One is@item.OS=window and @item.OS=Cloud.
I want to show If @item.OS=window then it show @item.OS && fa fa-window icon.If @item.OS=Cloud then it show @item.OS && fa fa -clud icon.

Comment: So all you need to do is write an `if` condition to output the relevant HTML. I'm sure you can manage that if you've already managed to write a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i am trying if condtion but its show error

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you told me how i am trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `item.OS` is a string value matching the class name you want to use or it has a `ToString()` override returning the same, you can use it directly with no need of if conditions:

```
<i class="fa fa-@item.OS.ToLower()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For a little more flexibility you can add a view helper via the @helper syntax. You can add this to the bottom of the view or to the App_Code folder to make it reusable across views.

For example:

```
@helper GetOSIconClass(string os)
{
    if(string.Equals(os, "window", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        @Html.Raw("\"fa fa-window\"");
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Raw("\"fa fa-cloud\"");
    }
}
```

This will give you the ability to use different class names to your values in OS (presuming you want them different). Its always good to keep things like class names in your views rather than in code.

An example of how to call it:

```
<i class=@GetOSIconClass(item.OS) aria-hidden="true">
```

More info here:
[Creating and Using a Helper in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site)